# write to text file typeerror join

Tags: python

I am trying to match elements from two lists and write it to a file, match columns from both the files col[0] and print certain columns in to a new file

```
with open('~/gf_out.txt', 'w') as w:
     w.write('\t'.join(headers) + '\n')
     for i in d1: #list1
         for j in d2: # list2
             if i[0] == j[0]:
                out = ((j[0:10]),i[1],i[2],j[11],j[12])
              # print out
                w.write('\t'.join(out) + '\n')

   TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found
```

if out changed to

```
out = (str(j[0:10]),i[1],i[2],j[11],j[12])
```

the final output would have [ ] around the first 10 columns, how can this be fixed

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.   
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Also, include the *full* error message and the desired output (actual example, not a brief description).

Comment: If you're "consistently being down voted", then read the comments and the posting guidelines to learn how to write a "proper" SO question.

Comment: this issue is very clearly relevant to what `i` and `j` are in this context, from the error I'm guessing they are lists but it is unclear what you want to happen with them. Please give an example of what `i` and `j` are, and what you want to end up in the file.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen edited my post

Comment: @Prune is it as per MCVE standards?

Comment: Much better, but not minimal yet.  The code snippet still isn't executable.  I see variables `headers`, 'd1', and 'd2' being undefined.  You can brute-force assign values for `headers`, 'd1', and 'd2'; their derivations are immaterial to the problem.  You could also replace `w.write` with a simple `print`, which elides the overhead of opening the output file.

In the meantime, I've retracted the down-vote: you have the basic idea.

Comment: `brute-force assign values for ` ?  @Prune I posted what I wrote d1 and d2 are list where i append elements  header is header  line for my final file to write  w.write: MCVE also states that post the exact code you have tried

Comment: "exact code" does not appear on that page.  The first bullet reads: `…Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem`

Comment: are you talking about the first block of code i asked or the one after edit? one after the edit has everything i tried

Comment: **Show an example of just `i = ... ; j = ...` for a single iteration then what you would expect to show up in the file.**  The code you just posted has inconsistent alignment, the tabs in the files have been replaced with spaces so `.split('\t')` won't work with the data copied from SO and the two snippits of the files don't contain any entries where `if i[0] == j[0]:` so the line in question wouldn't ever get run even if everything else was fine. I'd just like to work with `i` and `j` without any other code if that is possible.

Comment: `i = ['10:99951042-99951196(+)', 'ENSMUSG00000019971', 'Cep290']` . and `j=['10:99526780-99539369(+)', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'GT-AG', '12590', 'DA', 'Kitl', '0', 'ENSMUST00000020129,ENSMUST00000099320,ENSMUST00000105283,ENSMUST00000130190']`

Comment: each file has ~20000 rows cannot print the whole file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you wanting it to do? j[0:10] is a list, so if you want to convert it to a string, it will have square brackets. if you want those lements to be joind by tabs as well, you need to either do that explicitly or join it to the other list instead of embedding it.

`out = ('\t'.join(j[0:10]),i[1],i[2],j[11],j[12])`

or

`out = j[0:10] + [i[1],i[2],j[11],j[12]]`

Comment: `out = ('\t'.join(j[0:10]),i[1],i[2],j[11],j[12])` worked!

Answer (score 1):

**ANALYSIS**

Your problem is right where the error messge (certainly) told and, and just what it described ... once you're comfortable enough with Python to interpret the description.

```
out = ((j[0:10]),i[1],i[2],j[11],j[12])
w.write('\t'.join(out) + '\n')
```

`join` operates on a sequence of strings.  You gave it a sequence, but the first element of that is the tuple (j[0:10]).

**REMEDY**

You have nested lists, so you need nested `join`s.

```
sep = '\t'    # separator
out_0 = sep.join(j[0:10])
out_line = sep.join(out_0,,i[1],i[2],j[11],j[12])
w.write(out_line)
```

Yes, you can recombine this to a single-line `write`; I broke it down to make the logic clear.

If this doesn't match your needs, then please provide the required MCVE to clarify the problems.